# GLEW and my shader disagree - do I have that extension or not?

Tags: opengl, glsl, glew, opengl-extensions

I'm discovering shaders by use, and have come to a weird issue.

I need the `ARB_robustness` extension for my fragment shader to function properly. GLEW is positive that I have that extension :

```
assert(GLEW_ARB_robustness); // Passes
```

...however when I `require` it in my shader...

```
#extension GL_ARB_robustness : require
```

...the shader compiler does not recognize it.

```
0(3) : error C0202: extension ARB_robustness not supported
```

GLEW is correctly initialized, and everything works fine as long as I don't try to use that extension.

What could be the cause of this problem, and how could I solve it ? Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I'm poking at it on my side with the help of a friend, I ran `glxinfo` on his advice and the name of the extension does appear in the output.

Comment: do you have assertions enabled? maybe replace the assert with an `if(GLEW_ARB_robustness)printf("I am robust!");` and check again

Comment: @ratchetfreak Now my program happily boasts about being robust, then blows up the same way :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GL_ARB_robustness` is not a GLSL modifying extension. The intention of this extension is to make the interaction with the OpenGL API more robust in the sense that out-of-bound accesses to memory can be caught. Somewhat like the difference between `sprintf` and `snprintf`. Since this is not a shader extension it makes no sense to declare using it in the shaders.

*EDIT* Apart from that to actually have robustness support, the OpenGL context must be created with the robustness attribute enabled: See https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context_robustness.txt and https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context_robustness.txt – with robustness actually enabled for the context, the shader may also pass.

Comment: I found this extension while searching for a way of `texelFetch`ing out of the texture's bounds securely (returning pure black), so I supposed it was to be enabled in shaders. Could you expand a bit on how to create the context that way ? I'm currently using SDL2 on Linux, with `SDL_GL_CreateContext`.

Comment: @Quentin: Use `SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_ROBUST_ACCESS_FLAG);` *before* calling `SDL_GL_CreateContext (...)`, see [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GLcontextFlag) for more details.

Comment: @datenwolf I seem to have mixed up robustness and robust_buffer_access_behavior. From [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior.txt): "[...] if the context was created with robust buffer access enabled then instead of undefined behavior the result of the texel fetch is zero."